# Evaluating the integral of the Cantor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, cantor-set

Define the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}:=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$, where $G_1=(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$ and $G_n$ for $n>1$ is
the union of the middle-third open intervals in the intervals of $[0, 1]\setminus (\bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}G_j)$.

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{C}$ is also the set of numbers in $[0, 1]$ that have a base $3$ representation containing only $0$s and $2$s.

Define the Cantor function $\Lambda:[0,1]\to [0,1]$  as follows:

• If $x\in\mathcal{C}$, then $\Lambda(x)$ is computed from the unique base $3$ representation of $x$ containing only $0$s and $2$s by replacing each $2$ by $1$ and interpreting the resulting string as a base $2$ number.

• If $x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathcal{C}$, then $\Lambda(x)$ is computed from a base $3$ representation of $x$ by truncating after the first $1$, replacing each $2$ before the first $1$ by $1$, and interpreting the resulting string as a base $2$ number.

$\fbox{$\text{We want to compute }\int_{0}^{1}\Lambda(x).$}$

**what follows is what I have come up with to find the value of this integral; it is not completely rigorous although it could be made rigorous by induction but I reckon it would be very lengthy so I would like to know: (a) if what I have done is correct and (b) if there is another (perhaps shorter) and more rigorous proof of this result, thanks**

Since the Cantor set contains no interval with more than one element $\int_{\mathcal{C}}\Lambda=0$ so the only non-zero contribution to the value of the integral comes from the (constant) values that $\Lambda$ has on each middle-third open interval in $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$.
We have $$G_1 =(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}), G_2 =(\frac{1}{9},\frac{2}{9})\cup (\frac{7}{9},\frac{8}{9}), G_3 =(\frac{1}{27},\frac{2}{27})\cup (\frac{7}{27},\frac{8}{27})\cup (\frac{19}{27},\frac{20}{27})\cup (\frac{25}{27},\frac{26}{27}),$$ $$G_4 =(\frac{1}{81},\frac{2}{81})\cup (\frac{7}{81},\frac{8}{81})\cup (\frac{19}{81},\frac{20}{81})\cup (\frac{25}{81},\frac{26}{81})\cup (\frac{55}{81},\frac{56}{81})\cup (\frac{61}{81},\frac{62}{81})\cup (\frac{73}{81},\frac{74}{81})\cup (\frac{79}{81},\frac{80}{81})\dots$$

i.e. for each $n\geq 1$ we have $2^{n-1}$ disjoint open intervals, each of length $\frac{1}{3^n}$, which make up each $G_n$.
The $G_n$s, in ternary expansion, look like: $$G_1 =(0.1,0.2), G_2 =(0.01,0.02)\cup (0.21,0.22),$$ $$ G_3 =(0.001,0.002)\cup (0.021,0.022)\cup (0.201,0.202)\cup (0.221,0.222),$$ $$G_4 =(0.0001,0.0002)\cup (0.0021,0.0022)\cup (0.0201,0.0202)\cup (0.0221,0.0222)\cup (0.2001,0.2002)\cup (0.2021,0.2022)\cup (0.2201,0.2202)\cup (0.2221,0.2222)\dots$$

and by identifying each open interval in each $G_n$ by its leftmost endpoint we have:

$$G_1\to 0.1,\ G_2\to 0.01, 0.21,\ G_3\to 0.001, 0.021, 0.201, 0.221,$$ $$G_4\to 0.0001, 0.0021, 0.0201, 0.0221, 0.2001, 0.2021, 0.2201, 0.2221,\dots$$ so we see that we can find (the ternary expansion) of the left endpoints of all the intervals in $G_{n+1}$ by taking those of $G_n$ and substituting $01$ or $21$ to the last digit so each interval generates two other intervals: one to the left of it (the $01$ one) and one to the right of it (the $21$ one).

So, $$\Lambda(G_1)=\{0.1_2\}=\{\frac{1}{2}\}, \Lambda(G_2)=\{0.01_2,0.11_2\}=\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\},$$ $$ \Lambda(G_3)=\{0.001_2,0.011_2,0.101_2,0.111_2\}=\{\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8}\},$$ $$\Lambda(G_4)=\{0.0001_2,0.0011_2,0.0101_2,0.0111_2,0.1001_2,0.1011_2,0.1101_2,0.1111_2\}=\{\frac{1}{16},\frac{3}{16},\frac{5}{16},\frac{7}{16},\frac{9}{16},\frac{11}{16},\frac{13}{16},\frac{15}{16}\},\dots$$ hence we have that $G_n=\{\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{3}{2^n},\dots,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\}$ so $$\int_{0}^{1}\Lambda=\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} G_n}\Lambda=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{9}(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4})+\frac{1}{27}(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{5}{8}+\frac{7}{8})+\frac{1}{81}(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{7}{16}+\frac{9}{16}+\frac{11}{16}+\frac{13}{16}+\frac{15}{16})+\dots +\frac{1}{3^n}(\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots+\frac{2^n-1}{2^n})=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{4}{36}+\frac{16}{216}+\frac{64}{1296}+\dots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n-1}}{6^n}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{4}{6})^n=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{3})^n=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I didn't read the details of your calculation, so in particular I don't know if your Cantor function is the usual one. But if it is, i think an easier proof can be given by using that $\Lambda(x)=1-\Lambda(1-x)$ (how?!).